# Замена символов при помощи команды sed

Tags: linux, sed

Мне нужно в строке менять последнюю цифру

```
  "version": "0.0.1",
```

делаю это командой

```
sed  -i '/version/s/[^.]*$/'"2\"/" package.json
```

Но после получаю

```
"version": "0.0.2"
```

Как изменить команду так, чтоб она не стирала запятую в конце строки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed  -i '/version/s/[^.]*$/'"2\",/" package.json
```